# cannot get index of selected objects

Tags: jquery, indexing

I am sure this is quite simple, but I am having trouble getting the index of items within a list of selected elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $items = $('div.inner');
                console.log($items);
                $items.each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).index())
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="inner" id="div1"></div>
        <div class="outer"></div>

        <div class="inner" id="div2"></div>
        <div class="outer"></div>

        <div class="inner" id="div3"></div>
        <div class="outer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from the first console output, I have created a variable called $items, which has just three objects in. I need to get the index of each object within this collection.  I.e., indexes 0, 1 and 2. However, when looping through the collection, indexes 0, 2 and 4 are returned. If I add more divs with a class of outer, then the indexes change again.

What is happening here, and how do I get the indexes within the $items collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method returns the index of the element relative to its sibling elements, but what you are looking for is the index of the element in the list.

The [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/), gives the current elements index in the set as the first argument, you can use it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $items = $('div.inner');
    console.log($items);
    $items.each(function (idx) {
        console.log(idx)
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bb37p/)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure about  it

```
$(function () {
    $items = $('div.inner');
    $items.each(function (index) {
        console.log(index)
    })
});
```